# how do I convert a log file into a csv

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I have a script that tests my internet speed on an hourly basis to see how it differs throughout the day and night so I know when I'm getting my best speeds.  Now I have a "log file" which looks like this:

```
Date:  Fri Dec 12 19:01:01 EST 2014
Ping: 53.509 ms
Download: 25.19 Mbits/s
Upload: 9.47 Mbits/s
```

and I want to convert that into something usable.  I have not been able to find any help on reading that properly but if I could convert it to CSV or even read it directly into a mysql database that would be ideal, then I could work with it in a much more usable way.

Thank you,

Comment: This question is way too broad to answer right now, and not a 'concrete isolated solveable problem' as is required on Stack Overflow. Try something, and ask for help with specific issues when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, should give to you in CSV, separated by commas.

```
cut -d':' -f 2 file | paste -s -d ',,,
'  # behold the new line which alternates the sequence.
```

But why don't just have your script write out the CSV file instead of the log.  Or format it as an INSERT statement and pipe that to "mysql"?

Comment: that's great, the only hiccup is that it puts all of the values on the same line, where as the "Date:" how could I put that into a script where it would perform that action four times and then insert a new line?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but you need to be careful to hit an "enter" before you close the quotes.  The "-d" option to "paste" alternates through a sequence of characters, so first column comma, second column comma, third column comma, fourth column enter.  That is why it is coded above on what looks like to lines (in essence, it is).

Comment: that is perfect! I can just put that into a quick script that supstitutes file for the first switch